# XML node encryption in Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I need to insert couple of rows into a table where the values are inserted using XML.The problem I'm facing is the table contains a field 'password' which is varbinary in table definition and the value passed from front-end should be encrypted using a function in the database before insertion

```
@encryptUsername=dbo.Encrypt(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@userName))
```

I dont know how to do this when values are inserted using XML.

Following is the sample sp where values are inserted from XML

```
 INSERT INTO CLIENT(username,password)
   SELECT 
        Col.valueCol.value('(userName/text())[1]','VARCHAR'),
        Col.value('(password/text())[1]','VARCHAR')
 FROM @XmlData.nodes('/usernames/username')   Tab(Col)
```

here i need to get the xml node value 'password' and encrypt before it is add to table. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1566506-2799-1.aspx
It could be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is dangerous to use `varchar` or `nvarchar` without a length ([Bad habits to kick: Varchar without a length (Aaron Bertrand)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)).

As the `.value()` method returns a typed value, this is a `varchar(max)`, which you can pass over to your function directly. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO CLIENT(username,password)
   SELECT 
        dbo.Encrypt(Col.value('(userName/text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')),
        dbo.Encrypt(Col.value('(password/text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'))
 FROM @XmlData.nodes('/usernames/username')   Tab(Col)
```

**Attention** I took the above from your code, you use `Col.valueCol.value()` as well as `Col.value()`. I took the one I assume to be correct.

**Attention 2** You should change the `INSERT` statement to a `SELECT`-statement in order to check the result before you change your table's data...